# On hover of div a change the color of div b

Tags: css

I'm trying to get it so that when you hover div B then the background of div A changes.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/7257/)

```
<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

CSS

```
#b:hover ~ #a {
background: #ccc
}
```

Comment: The `selectorA ~ selectorB` syntax only works in one direction—it selects elements that match `selectorB` that are siblings of *and occur after* elements that match `selectorA`. In your example, `selector B` comes before `selector A` in the html. You will need to use javascript or a different HTML structure in order to achieve your desired result.

Comment: It's possible with flexbox to make the items appear in this order while they actually are the other way around in the html, see my updated answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select previous siblings on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994633/select-previous-siblings-on-hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it only if `#b` comes before `#a`, because

> **element1~element2** Selects *every* ***element2*** that are *preceded* by ***element1***

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/sgxonjwq/)

```css
#b:hover ~ #a {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="b">Div B</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div id="a">Div A</div>
```

or make it like `#a:hover ~ #b`

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/zdymzxmy/)

```css
#a:hover ~ #b {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

---

To achieve it using javascript can be done in many ways, here done by `.hover()` <sup>(*)</sup> function:

[**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cspww56f/)

```js
$('#a').hover(function(){
    $('#b').css({'background-color':'#CCC'});
}, function(){
    $('#b').css({'background-color':'transparent'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Why background color transparent? Seems like a better idea to save the current background color of #a to a variable on hover before changing the color so you can use that instead of transparent.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity is there a way to make a fade transition on the jquery? I tried adding `transition` to the css.

Comment: @seahorsepip, or he can just set the color he wants instead and save one line of code?

Comment: @user2252219 you can use `.addClass()` check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cspww56f/1/

Comment: addClass is risky since the class might be needed or already used in the css. I would instead add a data attribute and target that with css. So #a[data-hover] :)

Comment: @seahorsepip, with much respect, as you probably know, when it comes to programming there's usually more than one way to do things, specifiying a unique class in css for this is not that hard or mission impossible, also I'd rather add another class in css than using `data-*` attributes and keep the DOM intact, but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Css only method using flexbox to reorder #a and #b in the order you want while they actually are reversed in the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/15j14Ljb/

You can only affect child elements or elements after the hovered element with css :/

You can do it with jQuery (js) though:

```
var originalBackground;
$("#b").hover(function() {
    originalBackground = $("#a").css("background");
    $("#a").css("background", "#ccc");
}), function () {
    $("#a").css("background", originalBackground);
});
```

Or pure js:

```
var originalColor = document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor;
document.getElementById("b").onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
    document.getElementById("b").onmouseleave = function() {
        document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor = originalColor;
    }
```

Comment: I prefer the jQuery one. When I use that code though, the background will stay `#ccc` and not go back to white after you remove the hover.

Comment: My bad forgot to change the color back after hover. Updated the code to fix it, I made sure it sets the color back to the color it was the moment before it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple javascript solution.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var HEADER1 = document.getElementById("header");
  HEADER1.addEventListener("mouseover", display, false);
  HEADER1.addEventListener("mouseout", back1, false);
}, false);

function display() {
  var mainObject = document.getElementById("object");

  mainObject.style.display = "block";
}

function back1() {
  var mainObject = document.getElementById("object");
  mainObject.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: What for js chaos ia that?! Edit: see js added to my answer.

Comment: This is a pure javascript solution with jquery.

Comment: srry didnt notice our answer